# Can't generate an error response when user is not verifying recaptcha

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, recaptcha

everything is working perfectly but for some reason i can't generate a error response when the user is not checking the ReCaptcha button.
the form wont send until the user is checking that he is not a robot.

I built a controller for the recaptcha that works perfectly fine and the error msg that it is generating is indeed passed to the front-end with the error msg that i wrote.

as you can see in the image below all the error msg generated by the ajax script is perfectly fine and the 'g-recptcha-response' gets the error that I wrote in the controller but somehow the error only show up for the input fields.

[image]

The error response is generated by a ajax script that is handling errors from this code:
(ass you can see I tried handling the error locally in file with the @if statement that is right now with a comment)

```
<form action="{{ route('register')}}" id="signupForm" class="form-default submit-by-ajax" method="POST" prefix="signup">
                    @csrf
                    {{method_field('POST')}}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="{{ __('auth.First Name')}}" class="form-control signup-first_name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="{{ __('auth.Last Name')}}" class="form-control signup-last_name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="{{ __('auth.Email address')}}" class="form-control signup-email" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-group-password">
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="{{ __('auth.Password')}}" class="form-control signup-password" />
                        <img class="eye-password" src="{{asset('images/icon/eye.svg')}}" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-policy">
                        <label class="label-custom">
                            <input type="checkbox" required name="signup_agree">{{ __('auth.I agree to the')}}<a href="/page/terms-of-use">{{ __('auth.terms of service')}}</a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group align-self start justify-content center">
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{env('CAPTCHA_KEY')}}"></div>                   
                                <!--@if ($errors->has('g-recaptcha-response'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                @endif -->
                
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-submit">
                        <button class="btn" type="submit">{{ __('auth.Sign Up')}}</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-social text-center">
                        <p>{{ __('auth.or log in with:')}}</p>
                        <a href="{{route('login.socials', 'linkedin')}}"><img src="{{asset('images/icon/login-linkedin.svg')}}" alt="" /></a>
                        <a href="{{route('login.socials', 'google')}}"><img src="{{asset('images/icon/login-gmail.svg')}}" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-question">{{ __('auth.Already have an account?')}} <a href="" class="trigger-popup" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><b>{{ __('auth.Login')}}</b></a></div>
                </form>
```

Here is the content of the ajax.js file which is handling the errors from the signup.blade.php file

```
jQuery(function() {
    $("body").on("submit", ".submit-by-ajax", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const $form = $(this);
        const action = $form.attr("action");
        const method = $form.attr("method")
            ? $form.attr("method")
            : $form.children("input[name=_method]").val();
        const data = $form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: action,
            data,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $form.find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                clearForm($form);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                responseData(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                addValidateError($form, data);
            }
        });
    });

    function clearForm($form) {
        $form.find(".form-control").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
        });
        $form.find(".invalid-feedback").each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
    function addValidateError($form, data) {
        $form.find(":submit").attr("disabled", false);
        const prefix = $form.attr("prefix");
        const { errors } = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
        if (_.size(errors)) {
            _.forOwn(errors, (value, key) => {
                if(key == "g-recaptcha-response"){
                    //alert("Please Verigy that you are not a robot");
                    const CaptchaEle = $('.g-recaptcha');
                    const CaptchahtmlError = `<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>${_.first(
                        value
                    )}</strong></span>`;
                    CaptchaEle.addClass("is-invalid");
                    CaptchaEle.after($(CaptchahtmlError));
                } else{
                    const inputEle = $(`.${prefix}-${key}`);
                    const htmlError = `<span class="invalid-feedasdback" role="alert"><strong>${_.first(
                        value
                    )}</strong></span>`;
                    inputEle.addClass("is-invalid");
                    inputEle.after($(htmlError));
                }
                
                
                
            });
        }
    }
```

In the `if(key == "g-recaptcha-response")` the alert is indeed showing up if I am removing the comment.

Comment: someone? really need help here

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @Kuzma nope, still the same. 
any suggestions?